# How to autohide LocalNotification after interval in Capacitor?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor, localnotification

I have tried this code but getting error in timeoutAfter method as it is not recognized.

```
LocalNotifications.schedule({
      notifications: [
        {
          title: "Incoming Call",
          body: bodyValue,
          id: idValue,
          timeoutAfter: 3000
        },
      ],
    });
```

Although timeoutAfter method is available in Cordova plugin but not in Capacitor.